# What's the process between this two steps of this limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm reading a proof and when calculating a complex residue, this limit has to be computed:
$$\lim _{z \rightarrow(n+x)} \frac{(z-(n+x)) R(z)}{e^{2 \pi i z}-e^{2 \pi i x}}=\frac{R(n+x)}{2 \pi i e^{2 \pi i x}}$$
But I can't see where does the $2\pi i$ in the denominator come from. What's the process there? By the way, $R(z)$ is defined as a rational function, any, but I don't believe that influences the result.

Comment: L’Hopital’s rule?

Comment: @Fenris if L'hopital's rule was used, there would appear on the numerator $R'(n+x)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use L'hopital's rule.  We have, after taking derivatives, $\dfrac {R(z)+(z-(n+x))R'(z)}{2\pi i e^{2\pi iz}}\to\dfrac{R(n+x)}{2\pi ie^{2\pi ix}}$.

Comment: But how does the R'(z) dissappear?

Comment: Well, if $R$ is defined at $n+x$, then $R'(n+x)$ is defined.  But $z-(n+x)\to0$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you